# How to get monthly installment in a loan calculator?

Tags: python

I am new to coding, I cannot figure out the error in my assignment

Please look at the code below and help

```
#LOAN CALCULATOR ask for help
monthlyPayment = 0
loanAmount=input('please enter the loan amount \n')
##make the returned input a numeric value
float(loanAmount)
interestRate=input('please enter the interest rate \n')
##make the returned input a numeric value
float(interestRate)
numOfpay=input('please enter the number of installments \n')
##make the returned input a numeric value
float(numOfpay)
##monthlypayment = (L*(i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**(n)-1))
monthlyPayment= (loanAmount*(interestRate*(1+interestRate)**numOfpay) / ((1+interestRate)**(numOfpay)-1)) 

print(monthlyPayment)
```

I am expecting a monthly installment but get this

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: The value from commands like `float(loanAmount)` needs to be assign to the variable, like `loanAmount = float(loanAmount)`

Comment: Im not sure I completely understand the code, you are not assigning float(loanAmount) to any variable. Maybe you mean loanAmount=float(loanAmount) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you're trying to convert a value to a float (or any data type), you have to re-assign it to the same variable

`float(loanAmount)`
should be
`loanAmount = float(loanAmount)`

That will ensure it has converted data types.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I will pay more attention to details, going forward.